# Plotting Coordinates list as a line on Google Maps

Tags: google-maps

I have a list of 12000 Coordinates (Latitude/Longitude), I need to plot them as a line on Google Maps - what is the best way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You may have a look at the polylines samples for Google Maps API to get you started.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/polyline-simple

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/polyline-complex